# Xpath Selection of preceding-sibling check box in Div of generated table

Tags: c#, selenium, xpath

I'm having a bit of trouble with an xpath select.

I'm currently using C# and Selenium

I'm trying to overcome a problem whereby I need to select a checkbox within a generated table while only knowing a line of text in a preceding-sibling Div. All ID's can change as they are randomly generated.

I want to select class="jqx-checkbox-check-checked" while only knowing the text "testdata"

```
    <div role="row" style="position: relative; height:28px;" id="row1jqxgrid">
    <div role="gridcell" style="left: 0px; z-index: 790; width:30px;" class="jqx-grid-cell jqx-item jqx-grid-cell-alt jqx-grid-cell-selected jqx-fill-state-pressed">
        <div style="position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%; margin-top: -7px; margin-left: -10px; overflow: visible; cursor: auto;" id="jqxWidget3af6ac8d" tabindex="0" class="jqx-widget jqx-checkbox">
            <div class="jqx-checkbox-default jqx-fill-state-normal jqx-rc-all">
                <div style="width: 13px; height: 13px;"><span style="width: 13px; height: 13px;" class="jqx-checkbox-check-checked"></span></div>
            </div>
            <div style="clear: both;"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div role="gridcell" style="left: 30px; z-index: 789; width:25px;display: none;" class="jqx-grid-cell"></div>
    <div role="gridcell" style="left: 30px; z-index: 789; width:200px;" class="jqx-grid-cell jqx-item jqx-grid-cell-alt jqx-grid-cell-selected jqx-fill-state-pressed">
        <div class="jqx-grid-cell-left-align" style="margin-top: 6px;"><a id="id_01" href="/test/testing?id_01=199">testdata</a></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try `//div[div[div[text()="testdata"]]]//div/span`

Answer (score 0):

You can try to select the `row` that contains anywhere the string `testdata` and in that `row` select the `div` with the needed class.

A first try would be:

```
//div[@class='row'][.//div[text()='testdata']]//span[@class='jqx-checkbox-check-checked']
```

This would be the simplest way.

Answer (score 0):

You can select element with `testdata`, go to ancestor div and then go to span that you need:

```
//*[text()='testdata']/ancestor::div[@role='row']//span
```

You can also specify calss or part of the class of the span you need:

```
//*[text()='testdata']/ancestor::div[@role='row']//span[contains(@class,'checked')]

//*[text()='testdata']/ancestor::div[@role='row']//span[@class = 'jqx-checkbox-check-checked']
```